# How To Fix "list assignment index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to use a counter and an list to input a size then store it, but im hit with

list assignment index out of range

even thou range is set to the value of counter

```
while  counter < P_Ammount:
    P_Size[counter] = input("Enter A Size S= Small M= Meduim L= Large ")
    if P_Size[counter] == "S" or P_Size[counter] == "s": # both types of valadation for Lower and upper case
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 3.25 #Setting Price To List for Small

    if P_Size[counter] == "M" or P_Size[counter] == "m":
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 5.50 #Setting Price To List for Meduim

    if P_Size[counter] == "L" or P_Size[counter] == "l":
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 7.15 #Setting Price To List for Large

        counter + 1
```

Comment: can you show the whole code?

Comment: also, you should put `counter=counter + 1` out of last `if` indent. Check the answer below.

Comment: Moved the ```Counter + 1```

Comment: showing the whole code would be alot to put here above i have ```counter = 0``` and ```P_Size = []```

Comment: Check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
P_Size = []
P_Size_Cost = dict()
while  counter < P_Ammount:
    size = input("Enter A Size S= Small M= Meduim L= Large ")
    P_Size.append(size)

    if P_Size[counter] == "S" or P_Size[counter] == "s": # both types of valadation for Lower and upper case
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 3.25 #Setting Price To List for Small

    if P_Size[counter] == "M" or P_Size[counter] == "m":
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 5.50 #Setting Price To List for Meduim

    if P_Size[counter] == "L" or P_Size[counter] == "l":
        P_Size_Cost[counter] = 7.15 #Setting Price To List for Large

    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: even after using this and setting ```P_Size_Cost = []``` Still the same error comes up with this "list assignment index out of range"

Comment: `P_Size_Cost=dict()` has to be a dictionary not a list.